# Ставлю phpMyAdmin, но нет строк «extension=php_mbstring.dll» и «extension=php_mysqli.dll» в «php.ini»

Tags: phpmyadmin

Ставлю phpMyAdmin, но нет строк «extension=php_mbstring.dll» и «extension=php_mysqli.dll» в «php.ini», после этих строк нужно удалить точку с запятой для настройки программы. Что делать?

Туториал по установке: https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-phpMyAdmin-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-Windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите сюда описание изображения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Допишите эти строки сами

Comment: не сработало...